# Apache with SPDY enabled show HTTP/1.1 and not 2.0

Tags: apache-2.2, spdy

How I can make the requests shows HTTP 2.0 and not 1.1?
I'm sending requests with SPDY only and not 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Since [HTTP 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) is not yet a ratified standard and mod_spdy for Apache 2.2 only changes how the network connections are optimized I don't think that is possible.

The [Protocol Version Policy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/compliance.html#policyversion) only supports:

- HTTP/1.1
- HTTP/1.0
- HTTP/0.9

From the mod_spdy [manual](http://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-protocol/spdy-protocol-draft3-1#TOC-3.-HTTP-Layering-over-SPDY):

> SPDY is intended to be as compatible as possible with current web-based applications. This means that, from the perspective of the server business logic or application API, the **features of HTTP are unchanged**. To achieve this, all of the application **request and response header semantics are preserved**, although the syntax of conveying those semantics has changed. Thus, the rules from the HTTP/1.1 specification in RFC2616 apply...

emphasis mine.